# How to install visual studio 2015 update 2 and not 3

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Because Visual studio 2015 update 3 causes all sorts of mayhem on our systems, I'd like to install 2015 update 2. However, if I download the 2015.2 installers, even the ISO, it wants to install update 3 and it doesn't give me the option to just install update 2. Even when running 'VS2015.2.exe /norefresh /noweb' it will install update 3!

Does anybody know how to get update 2 installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have had visual studio 2015 installed before, and want to install it again, it might not tell you that it's already on your system. Try to get an installer that gives you the option to uninstall it. For me that meant using the following ISO:
en_visual_studio_professional_2015_with_update_2_x86_x64_dvd_8509105

If you have a similar issue, good luck!